# Why reprex cannot render %>% results

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, magrittr, reprex

I have no problem making this tibble:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
as.tibble(mtcars[2:3,2:3]) %>% mutate(cyl_x_disp = cyl * disp)
```

Which produce this:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
    cyl  disp cyl_x_disp
  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1     6   160        960
2     4   108        432
```

But when I tried to wrap it with **[reprex](https://github.com/jennybc/reprex)**

```
reprex::reprex(as.tibble(mtcars[2:3,2:3]) %>% mutate(cyl_x_disp = cyl * disp))
```

The clipboard showed this:

```
as.tibble(mtcars[2:3, 2:3]) %>% mutate(cyl_x_disp = cyl * disp)
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "%>%"
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put package loading also into expression, otherwise the example is not reproducible:

```
reprex::reprex({
    library(tibble)
    library(dplyr)
    as.tibble(mtcars[2:3,2:3]) %>% mutate(cyl_x_disp = cyl * disp)
})
```

This will produce:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
as.tibble(mtcars[2:3, 2:3]) %>% mutate(cyl_x_disp = cyl * disp)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>     cyl  disp cyl_x_disp
#>   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     6   160        960
#> 2     4   108        432
```